# How to do a std::map lookup

Tags: c++, c++11

So this is a segment of my code:

```
std::map<int, std:string> tagMap = {{1, "data"},{2,"entry"},{3,"id"}}

....

/* ORIGINAL
for (auto& node: doca.child("data").children("entry")) {
    const char* id = node.child_value("id");
    mapa[id] = node;
}
*/


for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap.find(1)).children(tagMap.find(2))) {
    const char* id = node.child_value(tagMap.find(3));
    mapa[id] = node;
}
```

I am trying to replace a fixed definition with one from a map lookup. I wasn't sure quite how to implement this and my approach didn't seem to work. I was wondering if anyone could tell me the right approach to do this please?

Comment: Hey Jimmy, would you be able to add some more context and maybe some more example code to this question? It's not easy to understand what you're trying to do with the code above (and it might be as simple as changing variable names to align correctly + a small amount more context)

Comment: `std::map::find` returns an iterator. I'm guessing that's not what you want.

Comment: @SJoshi The rest of the code is a bit broken so might confuses things. I have the commented code at the moment but it has hardcoded mappings to tag names. The code below it is what I want to do, same code but with map lookup to get the value.

Comment: I want tagMap.find(3) to return id

Comment: @SiggiSv Please see edited question. The map at the top is now called tagMap

Comment: What are `child` and  `children`?

Comment: @Arun Its for XML parsing. I don't want to include code because really the question is just how to take code with static definitions and change it so it looks up its definitions from the map

Comment: @Jimmy tagMap is an `std::map` object. So tagMap.find() is a `std::map::find` function which returns an iterator object, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible suggestion of what you're trying to, as in, here is a map lookup:

```
std::map<int, std::string> tagMap = {{1, "data"},{2,"entry"},{3,"id"}};
std::cout << tagMap[1] << std::endl;  // returns 'data'
std::cout << tagMap[2] << std::endl;  // returns 'entry'
std::cout << tagMap[3] << std::endl;  // returns 'id'
```

And without the supporting code, I can't see what doca is, so this is probably as far as I can take it.

```
for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
    const char* id = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
    mapa[id] = node;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how do I put the value in my code. P.s Sorry I just edited my code, mapping was meant to be called tagMap

Comment: @Jimmy Not .[1] just tagMap[1] would return the string embedded in the map.